# Multi select custom adapter with search and checkbox

Tags: android, listactivity

I am new in Android application development.

I want to create search and select functionality in  ListActivity with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL. Below is the UI like this I want to create my listview .

I stuck on this from two days anyone has the solution or way to do it.

[image: ListActivity]

Comment: Did you got the solution for this

Comment: @ArnoldBrown, this post is quite old in Year 2015. I used Simple custom list view and tag view to select multiple rows. I would suggest to create new thread for your issues as there is been quite big updates after I created this post.